# Parallelize processing of collection

Tags: scala

I have a Seq() with a significant number of entries(50K suppose) - each being an ID.

```
Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6 ..... 50000)
```

There is a blocking function, which takes a Seq as an input,loads the entities corresponding to each id, and return a separate Iterable[Entity].

```
def getEntityFromID(id: Seq[Int]): Ierable[Entity]
```

How do I parallelize this operation on the above Seq - in batches of x , and collect the entries into a single Seq().

Comment: If you want to use just plain scala, you have [parallel collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html). If that is not the case, please add more details about what are the stack used. Without context, this is a broad question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do *grouped(i)* on the initial seq and get subsequest sequences of i size

then iterate those and call getEntityFromID

```
  val list : Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6..... 50000)
  val groupedList = list.grouped(3)
  
  groupedList.flatMap{
    gp => getEntityFromID(gp)
  }

  def getEntityFromID(id: Seq[Int]): Iterable[Entity] = ???
```

to execute groupedList in parallel you can use

```
 groupedList.toList.par.flatMap{
    gp => getEntityFromID(gp)
  }
```

you can also control prallelism using

```
  val parallelCollection = groupedList.toList.par
  parallelCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
    new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(20)
  )

  parallelCollection.flatMap{
    gp => getEntityFromID(gp)
  }
```

above code executes 20 items at a time

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to "slide" over the sequence using **.sliding(size, step)** which returns **Iterator[Seq[Int]]**, you can then do the call to the **getEntityFromID** from each Seq and wrap it in a future. To then get the results you can await the futures.

As an example:

```
  val s = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
  def getEntityFromID(w: Seq[Int]) = w.map(_+1)

  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
  val s2: List[Future[Seq[Int]]] = s.sliding(3, 3).map(w => Future(getEntityFromID(w))).toList
  val s3: List[Int] = s2.flatMap(f => Await.result(f, 2 second))
  println(s3)
```

Of course it's still blocking and waiting for subsequent calls to finish, but it's one way to do it.
A good idea is always to wrap a call to an external service in a future as you don't know how long it will take (or if it will return a valid answer).

It's a basic answer here I can give at best without making assumptions about the use case.